# How to use Database in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Can anybody tell me how to use database in Sencha Touch?

Please suggest some code or example.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at **Ext.data.Store** http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

You can't use your Database directly, you have to implement this layer between Frontend and Backend (Server-Side or also a Client Side Backend, like HTML5 Webstorage).

Client side example from linked sencha docs:

```
// Set up a model to use in our Store
Ext.define("User", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: "firstName", type: "string"},
            {name: "lastName",  type: "string"},
            {name: "age",       type: "int"},
            {name: "eyeColor",  type: "string"}
        ]
    }
});

var myStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    model: "User",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url : "/users.json",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "users"
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.create("Ext.List", {
    fullscreen: true,
    store: myStore,
    itemTpl: "{lastName}, {firstName} ({age})"
});
```

Serverside depends on your environment. If you use a server based backend implement a REST API in the programming language of your choice.

In order to store data on the local device/browser you have to implement the LocalStorage proxy. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

Comment: I want to store data and when application open back then want to use that data.

Comment: So you have to used the above mentioned Ext.data.Store with the LocalStorage proxy (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) this allows you to store data in the client's browser without the need of an server backend.